# start the job immediately using quartz framework?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, scheduledexecutorservice

I am running some jobs periodically using `quartz framework`. I have a below `quartz_config` xml file which contains all the jobs I am running and at what interval.

```
<job-scheduling-data
    xmlns="http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/xml/JobSchedulingData"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/xml/JobSchedulingData http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/xml/job_scheduling_data_2_0.xsd"
    version="1.8">

    <schedule>
        <job>
            <name>ParserApp</name>
            <job-class>com.process.task.ParserApp</job-class>
        </job>
        <trigger>
            <cron>
                <name>ParserApp</name>
                <job-name>ParserApp</job-name>
                <cron-expression>0 0 0/3 1/1 * ? *</cron-expression>
            </cron>
        </trigger>
    </schedule>

</job-scheduling-data>
```

I am running `ParserApp` job every 3 hours. Now what I have noticed is - whenever I start my application, it doesn't start `ParserApp` job immediately. What it does instead is, it starts `ParserApp` jobs after 3 hours only which is fine as per cron expression. Is there any way by which I can start `ParserApp` job immediately whenever application is started up and then next run should happened after 3 hours only just like java `ScheduledExecutorService` does?

In the below code, as soon as you start `executorService`, it will call `parserApp` immediately and then it will call `parserApp` again after 3 hours periodically. Is there any way to do the same thing using `quartz-scheduler`?

```
executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    parserApp();
  }
}, 0, 3, TimeUnit.HOURS);
```

Below is how I am starting all the jobs using quartz scheduler:

```
StdSchedulerFactory factory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
try {
  factory.initialize(App.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("quartz.properties"));
  Scheduler scheduler = factory.getScheduler();
  // starts all our jobs using quartz_config.xml file
  scheduler.start();
} catch (SchedulerException ex) {
  logger.logError("error while starting scheduler= ", ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(ex));
}
```

Comment: I do this scheduling a single execution of my job on application startup and keep cron schedule  to run every T times.

Comment: The way to replicate what you have using executorService is to use SimpleTriggers. Take a look at examples here http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-05.html